# jQuery target and click binding for when user leaves specified target

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am working to create a table that can be edited from the grid layout.

**Goal**: If a user double-clicks a row/column that is editable, the `input` can be manipulated. Then when they click outside of this object, it would fire an `$.ajax` event, saving their changes.

I have a working example of the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3enw/5/ 
You'll see that while it does work to edit, anytime you click anywhere it says that you've clicked outside the container.

**jQuery code**:

```
$(".canEdit").dblclick(function () {
   $(this).find("input").attr("readonly", false).css("background", "white");
   var container = $(this); //set area to see when clicked outside
   $(document).click(function (e) {
     if (!container.is(e.target)) {
       alert("clicked outside container");
       //handle ajax submission since they left
      } else {
       console.log("still inside container");
       //do nothing, allow them to continue editing
      }
   });
});
```

**ISSUE**: Is there a better way to handle knowing when a user has clicked outside the previously double-clicked area? I was thinking that tieing a `e.stopPropogation();` would suffice but it doesn't stop the function long enough to double-click a new row. Perhaps I should not use `$(document).click` as this binds the document to that single event?

Let me know if further information is needed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if (container.find(e.target).length<=0)` `// which will check whether container contains clicked element.`

instead of

`if (!container.is(e.target))` `//which will check container (i.e., td in your case) is equal to e.target which will be input/child elements.`

Try this:

```
$(".canEdit").dblclick(function () {
    $(this).find("input").attr("readonly",false).css("background","white");
    var container = $(this); //set area to see when clicked outside
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if (container.find(e.target).length<=0) {
            alert("clicked outside container");
            //handle ajax submission since they left
        } else {
            console.log("still inside container");
            //do nothing, allow them to continue editing
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3enw/7/)**

Comment: This makes more sense. I just tested on my site and it's worked as needed. Thanks for the help and the `.length` explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a blur function instead? like so:

```
$(".canEdit").dblclick(function () {
    $(this).find("input").attr("readonly",false).css("background","white")
    .blur(function () {
        alert(1);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZbkL/)

You could also separate the css and use `addClass()`

```
$(".canEdit").dblclick(function () {
    $(this)
    .find("input")
    .attr("readonly",false)
    .addClass('editable')
    .blur(function () {
        alert(1);
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zTR9w/)

Comment: I like this thinking because `.blur()` also handles it if the user tabs out of the `input`. While it's not applicable in my current layout I'll keep it in mind! Thanks for the input!